# Pushing private repository to Docker Hub fails: HTTP code 504 while uploading metadata

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I am trying to push a private repository to Docker hub and I am repeatedly getting the following error:

**HTTP code 504 while uploading metadata: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value**

This repository was pushed successfully before. But today it ends up with this error. How can I push it successfully?

```
$ docker push myname/myrepo

Sending image list
Pushing repository myname/myrepo (1 tags)
99910ed13f45: Image already pushed, skipping
3932a42550ef: Pushing
2014/12/16 10:10:35 HTTP code 504 while uploading metadata: invalid character '<' looking for
```

### Update

It pushed finally after about 10 attempts. I wonder what could cause those failures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered the same issue in my max os x, search around also no clue, don't know why, anyway, when I re-run the push, it's disappear, it seems an intermittent issue.